# New to ubuntu, want to rename files, but how?

Tags: files, downloads, rename

We have a new computer and I love the Ubuntu design, but the code-stuff is a bit hard for me...

So here is my question:

I just downloaded something from youtube and converted it to an mp3. I have last.fm, that is a site that connects between the media player and the site, and it stores your listening history. When I play my song it says "unknown artist". When I go to my downloads, the song and then properties and click on audio I can not change a thing! How can I change the title, artist and all that other stuff?

The answers that I think I found are with all these weird codes and I don't even know if that is the solution for my "problem"..

Thanks for responding!

Comment: Do you want to rename the file (file name) or edit the meta tags like Artist, Title, Year, Genre, etc.? The latter requires an [ID3 tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) editor to be installed. Does an application like [easytag](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/easytag/) solve your issue or do you require this to be editable in Nautilus (file manager) itself?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the id3 tags? If you are, you should consider editing the title to clarify it.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu doesn't support editing id3 tags by default. You will have to use a seperate application to do it. Rhythmbox can provide this functionality and comes preinstalled in Ubuntu.

Open the mp3 file in Rhythmbox. 
Right click the song in Rhythmbox and select `Properties`. This will give you options for changing Artist/Album/Title etc.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being off-topic, but what is that theme/window decorator you're using? It's beautiful!

Comment: I'm using the Numix theme. :) (http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/beautiful-numix-gtk3-theme-released.html)

Answer (score 4):

The Artist's Name, Album Title, Year etc (which you can view when you click *properties* ), are called ID3 tags.

In that case you would have to search for ID3 editors to edit that piece of information. You could take a quick look at the Ubuntu Software Centre or look at the internet. ( [EasyTag](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easytag/) for example, as mentioned in Mitch's answer ).

I think you will be able to edit that information with **[Rhythmbox](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/)** (preinstalled) as well as with **[Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/)**.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rename the file just right click on the file in file manager and select rename as shown

[image: Nautilus]

---

If however what you want to do is edit the mp3 tags: Title, Artist etc.  You can do that in Rhythmbox.  Right click on the mp3 file select properties

[image: Rhythmbox]

You can edit in the box that opens.

[image]

There are also other applications in the software centre which may be better if you have a lot of these to edit; such as [**EasyTag**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easytag/)

Answer (score 2):

Try EasyTAG

EasyTAG is an utility for viewing, editing and writing the ID3 tags of different audio files, using a GTK+ interface.

To install click [**EasyTAG** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easytag/)

<sup>Source: Ubuntu Apps</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/). Open your file with Clementine, select your track in the playlist, right click on the song and click on "`Edit track information`". If you do not want to right click on your track you can also use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

I know that other answers tell you to use Rhythmbox instead of Clementine but this last has got an advantage. It has got a feature which is able to find the missing informations for you ! A kind of Shazam in a way. For this, open your file with Clementine, select your track in the playlist, right click on the song and click on "`Complete tags automatically`". If you do not want to right click on your track you can also use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut. Quite useful, isn't it ?